# Amplify React - Cognito-remove signup in login page

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-amplify

There is a SO question [How to remove signup in login page][1] and it addresses CF. In case of Amplify, CF template is generated by `backend-config.json`

```json
  "auth": {
    "usermanager": {
      "service": "Cognito",
      "serviceType": "managed",
      "providerPlugin": "awscloudformation",
     }
   }
```

How to configure Amplify template to generate CF template with property?

```yaml
AdminCreateUserConfig:
          AllowAdminCreateUserOnly: True
```

Link to Amplify templeate reference would be appreciated.

Edit:
Amplify supports overriding generated content. I run `amplify override auth`. It generated file `amplify\backend\auth\myusermanager\override.ts`. I did one override:

```js
import { AmplifyAuthCognitoStackTemplate } from '@aws-amplify/cli-extensibility-helper';

export function override(resources: AmplifyAuthCognitoStackTemplate) {
    resources.userPool.adminCreateUserConfig = {
        allowAdminCreateUserOnly: true,
    }
}
```

Generated CF template looks OK

```json
  "Resources": {
    "UserPool": {
      "Type": "AWS::Cognito::UserPool",
      "Properties": {
        "AdminCreateUserConfig": {
          "AllowAdminCreateUserOnly": true
        },
```

Regardless of it, **Sign in** link is present on login page.
When I check Cognito user pool policy, I find `Only allow administrators to create users` radio button selected.

**EDIT**
Suggested answer relates to VUE. I am using React.
`"@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^2.1.0"`
[1]: [AWS Cognito-remove signup in login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54782815/aws-cognito-remove-signup-in-login-page)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable the sign up link for the aws amplify vue authenticator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60045960/how-do-i-disable-the-sign-up-link-for-the-aws-amplify-vue-authenticator)

Comment: It looks to me overkilling. Amplify allows "overriding" CF template generation. I edited question

Comment: Actually, it works. I tried to signup new user and got error: "SignUp is not permitted for this user pool". I was expecting that Sign up link will not be shown on login dialog. It is usability question. Login dialog should be created based on Cognito settings.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by passing `hideSignUp` to `Authenticator`

```
return (
  <Authenticator hideSignUp>
    {({ signOut, user }) => (
      <main>
        <h1>Hello {user?.username}</h1>
        <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
      </main>
    )}
  </Authenticator>
);
```